# subprocess.call logger info and error for stdout and stderr respectively

Tags: python, logging

I have a logger. something like this:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('myApp')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('myApp.log')
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

I am calling an external process like this:

```
subprocess.call("someCommand")
```

I want to capture stdout and stderr seperatly from that process so that I can log them acccordingly. For example

```
logger.info(<stdout>)
logger.error(<stderr>)
```

I see various ways to capture all of the subprocess in one stream. But, if there is an actual error, I would like to log it as such. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `subprocess.Popen()` and call `.communicate()` on the returned process object:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["someCommand"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

if stdout:
    logger.info(stdout)
if stderr:
    logger.error(stderr)
```

Comment: Thanks. So easy. Another reason to like Python

Comment: This breaks down a bit when stdout or stderr has a lot of data, since `.communicate()` buffers the data. Some people might want to call `logger` as soon as a line is available from either pipe.

Comment: Use `subprocess32` with `bufsize`.